# C programming : Creating substring

Tags: c

I'm new in C and I need some explanation on what I am doing wrong.

I'm trying to iterate over a string and find the first '\' then make a substring from that place in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {

    struct info{
        char* name;
        char* type;
        char* path;
    };
    struct info user1;

    char* a = "/home/users/user1";

    for (int i = strlen(a) ; i < 0 ; i--) {
        printf("%d",i);
        if(strcmp(a[i],'/')==0){
            strncpy(a,user1.name,i);
            break;

        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to tell what the problem is. Does the code compile? If not, what is the error message? Does it compile but not work properly? If so, what is the output and what did you expect it to be?

Comment: You mean "last", right? Since you're looping from the end of the string? Also, it should be `i >= 0` since otherwise if the first character (at index 0) is the one you're looking for, you won't find it.

Comment: error message is : finished with exit code 11.  i>0 will go on forever since i'm iterating from the end of the array. I tried to use printf instead of strlcpy but looks like my if statement is the fault. i know i need to change to i<=0 as unwind mentioned but it won't fix the problem.

Comment: Your compiler should scream in pain: `strcmp(a[i],'/')` The second parameter is not a pointer to a string but a single character. Please always enable warnings during compilation when you run into problems.

Comment: Hint: String literals mustn't be written to. `strncpy(a,user1.name,i);` `a` points to read only memory.

Comment: my compiler didnt scream at all. i will look on how to enable warning in clion. thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors I will explain them one by one. The code will be something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {

    struct info{
        char* name;
        char* type;
        char* path;
    };
    struct info user1;
    user1.name = malloc(40);
    if( user1.name == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
        exit(1);
    }

    const char* a = "/home/users/user1";

    for(int i = strlen(a) -1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if(a[i]=='/'){
            strncpy(user1.name,a+i+1,i);
            user1.name[i]='\0';
            break;
        }


    }
    printf("%s\n",user1.name );
    free(user1.name);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Things you did wrong

- There was no memory allocated to `name` it was simply an uninitialized pointer. Here we have allocated memory to it.
- Second thing, `strcmp` as the name suggests compares null terminated char array not `char`-s. It can be done with simple `==` operator.
- The copy part is modified to only copy the user name part nothing else. That's why we have incremented the pointer to point to the correct position.
- You forgot to check the return value of `malloc` and then you should free the allocated memory.
- Also you can't modify a string literal because it stays in non-modifiable portion of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {

    struct info{
        char* name;
        char* type;
        char* path;
    };
    struct info user1;
    user1.name = malloc(10); 
    char* a = "/home/users/user1";
     int len=strlen(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d",i);
        if(a[i]=='/'){
            strncpy(user1.name,a+i+1,i);
        user1.name[i]='\0';
        break;

        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```